# Migrate private repo from Github to Gitorious

Tags: git, github, gitorious

I am hoping to eliminate my monthly bill paid for my private repositories on Github.

I have created a Gitorious account and would like to know an easy way to migrate just my sources and history.

Somewhat the reverse of this question:
[Import into github from gitorious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067010/import-into-github-from-gitorious)

Comment: Assuming gitorious supports the git protocol, the answer should be the same as the StackOveflow you posted, just in reverse.

Comment: Good enough then. I was hoping for more of the import functionality used in bit bucket.